# How to consume a spring rest api which is protected by OAuth2Sso?

Tags: rest, redirect, oauth-2.0, swagger

Good afternoon everyone.
I have a dilemma.
Recently I have been assigned to create an API Documentation with Swagger 2, version 2.6.1 using SpringFox and the @EnableSwagger2 annotation. After doing so, I was given the task to "secure" it, preferably with Oauth2. At the beginning I have researched how to do it, and after many trials and errors I gave up and came up with the idea of securing the whole package and apis. My method of doing it was the following. I created a basic Oauth2 server and client folowing some tutorials on the web and I've added the swagger and the rest methods in the client. The client works in the following manner. After i enter on the site http://localhost:8082/ui/index.html, it prompts me to login. I press on login, it redirects me to the login form on the auth server at http://localhost:8081/auth/login where I enter my credentials, and after that it redirects me to my swagger. If i enter any of the links from the client in the browser url, it forwards me to the index.html if i haven't logged in previously.

My problem is that right now, Swagger works, is secured and all, but if try to call my methods from postman It displays my login page in html. I am a beginner in rest apis, can you give me some indications?

I have used the following code to do the redirects.

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    super.addViewControllers(registry);

    registry.addViewController("/")
            .setViewName("forward:/index");

    registry.addViewController("/index");
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/ui/v2/api-docs", "/v2/api-docs").setKeepQueryParams(true);
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/ui/swagger-resources/configuration/ui","/swagger-resources/configuration/ui");
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/ui/swagger-resources/configuration/security","/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/ui/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources");
    registry.addViewController("/api");


}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/").addResourceLocations("/ui");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/ui/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
}
```

For example, if I acces http://localhost:8082/ui/api2/getConf, one of the methods for the api, if I am not logged in, I redirects me to the login.

If i have to test the api with postman, how can I integrate the login into it?
The login is based on a user and password.

Thank you.

Comment: To test your app you can use token, provided by your security token service (STS). Usually you can see it in network trace of your browser

Comment: I resolved it. It seems that i didn't know how to use postman the proper way. I generated a new token directly from postman. Initially I've taken tokens from network trace.